# Searching and past the last value of a text file from a output software

Tags: bash, unix, awk, conditional-statements

I made several analysis in a software and the out put file is similar to this:

```
ASReml 4.1 [28 Dec 2014] Analisys   Build mx [05 Oct 2018]   64 bit  Linux (x64)
 31 Jan 2020 07:26:33.206   1024 Mbyte        
 *****************************************************************
 * Contact support@asreml.co.uk for licensing and support        *
 *********************************************************** ARG *
Forming   136206 equations:   2 dense.
 Initial updates will be shrunk by factor    0.316
 Notice: Algebraic Denominator DF calculation is not available
         Numerical derivatives will be used.
 Notice: LogL values are reported relative to a base of -150000.00    
 Notice: 8 singularities detected in design matrix.
   1 LogL=-5856.80     S2=  481.74      42059 df 
   2 LogL=-5617.63     S2=  443.14      42059 df 
   3 LogL=-5405.81     S2=  393.42      42059 df 
   4 LogL=-5323.54     S2=  353.37      42059 df 
   5 LogL=-5309.22     S2=  327.81      42059 df 
   6 LogL=-5308.88     S2=  321.50      42059 df 
   7 LogL=-5308.88     S2=  320.63      42059 df 

          - - - Results from analysis of weight - - -
 Akaike Information Criterion   310623.75 (assuming 3 parameters).
 Bayesian Information Criterion 310649.69
```

I want to copy the value of the last LogL and pass it to a separate file, that is, -5308.88, as each analysis is different, the position of the LogL changes, so I need a condition. I believe that the principle is this: `paste <(awk 'FNR==12 {print $2}' df) >> file.results`, but as I need a condition for the last LogL value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tac` + `awk` solution.

```
tac file | awk 'match($0,/LogL=-[0-9]+|LogL=-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5);exit}'
```

`tac` will read Input_file from last line to first line and in `awk` we are making sure only very first occurrence of `LogL` is being read and exiting after it is found, thus we need NOT to keep track of last occurrence because we converted it to first occurrence by `tac`. Also regex has taken care negative non floating values capture also.

Comment: @CuriousG., When I run `tac Input_file | awk 'match($0,/LogL=-[0-9]+|LogL=-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6);exit}'` it worked fine for me.Any error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, but if the value is positive will be this way `Logl= 5308.88`, and the command don't work. I tried to fix, but I didn't able to do this. What I need to change?

Comment: To work for negative and positive values. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @CuriousG., Sure, could you please try `tac Input_file | awk 'match($0,/LogL=-[0-9]+|LogL=-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|LogL=[0-9]+|LogL= +[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6);exit}'` I haven't tested it since I am having my Dinner, you could lemme know if this helped you.

Comment: Perfect, u are the best.

Comment: Sorry again, the same problem, just taking positive values, sorry for my silly mistake..